# Html Agility Pack - Remove element, but not innerHtml

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I can easily remove the element just by note.Remove() lik this:

```
HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();

html.Load(Server.MapPath(@"~\Site\themes\default\index.cshtml"));

foreach (var item in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//removeMe"))
{
    item.Remove();
}
```

But that removes the innerHtml as well.
What if i only want to remove the tag, and keep the innerHtml?

Example:

```
<ul>
    <removeMe>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Keep me</a>
        </li>
    </removeMe>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Find the parent node of the `removeMe` node and append the innerHtml of the `removeMe` node to the parent node's innerHtml and _then_ remove it? :-)

Comment: Thought about that, but what if the parent node contains 5 nested nodes, and removeMe is number 3, then if i append the innerHtml of removeMe to the parent node, the position is no longer the same.

Comment: Well perhaps you can in fact replace the removeMe node by its innerHtml, or insert after the previous node, haven't got that much experience _replacing_ HTML using HTMLAP, but browsing and walking the DOM tree is really easy.

Comment: Another solution would be to use the InsertAfter on the remove me, and insert the innerHtml, and then remove removeMe, but i dont know how to  use insertAfter properly.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Good idea trying it out now. Edit, there's no replace method, only a replaceChild method.

Comment: `item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(item.InnerHtml), item);` This would do it, but `HtmlNode.CreateNode(item.InnerHtml)` doesn't seem to generate any html.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't help with that. Perhaps the docs or forums (or other questions on SO) can provide some guidance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//removeme");
node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
```

Comment: "bool KeepGrandChildren", this is definitely the best solution, thank you!

Comment: nice, does it work for you? i get always that Exception: Node "<previousNode><previousNode>" was not found in the collection - my test html: <ul><test></test><removeMe><li><a href=\"#\">Keep me</a></li></removeMe></ul> - also when i test it with that : "<ul><removeMe><li><a href=\"#\">Keep me</a></li></removeMe></ul>" then i get Unexpected error.

Comment: That is strange, it works for me, even when there is no parent node.

Comment: If the removeme tag had text in it, the text will be removed also. For example <removeme>text<p>more text</p></removeme> will become <p>more text</p>

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//removeMe"))
{
    if (item.PreviousSibling == null)
    {
        //First element -> so add it at beginning of the parent's innerhtml
        item.ParentNode.InnerHtml = item.InnerHtml + item.ParentNode.InnerHtml;
    }
    else
    {
        //There is an element before itemToRemove -> add the innerhtml after the previous item
        foreach(HtmlNode node in item.ChildNodes){
            item.PreviousSibling.ParentNode.InsertAfter(node, item.PreviousSibling);
        }
    }
    item.Remove();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for my test cases. :) I am not sure why you did the HTML concatenation part.

Comment: This will produce an ordering bug if there are previous siblings; you have to iterate through the childnodes collection backwards.

Answer (score 3):

There is a problem with the bool KeepGrandChildren implementation for people that might have text withing the element they are trying to remove. If the removeme tag had text in it, the text will be removed also. For example `<removeme>text<p>more text</p></removeme>` will become `<p>more text</p>`

Try this:

```
private static void RemoveElementKeepText(HtmlNode node)
    {
        //node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node, true);
        HtmlNode parent = node.ParentNode;
        HtmlNode prev = node.PreviousSibling;
        HtmlNode next = node.NextSibling;

        foreach (HtmlNode child in node.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (prev != null)
                parent.InsertAfter(child, prev);
            else if (next != null)
                parent.InsertBefore(child, next);
            else
                parent.AppendChild(child);

        }
        node.Remove();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but as written this still produces the same ordering bug that's in the release code!  In your foreach loop you need to iterate backwards for the children to appear in order.

Comment: The release I was working with didn't reverse the order so I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I see you were addressing a different bug.  Here is the one I am talking about: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/79587 If you look at the source for `HtmlNode.RemoveChildren()` you will see your code includes the same bug; you need to process and insert grandchildren in reverse order for them to come out right.

Answer (score 2):

Adding my two cents because none of these approaches handled what I wanted (to remove a set of given tags like `p` and `div` and handle nesting properly while preserving inner tags).

Here's what I came up with and passes all my unit tests with what I would consider most of the cases I need to deal with:

```
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();

// load html
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var tags = (from tag in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
           where tagNames.Contains(tag.Name)
           select tag).Reverse();

// find formatting tags
foreach (var item in tags)
{
    if (item.PreviousSibling == null)
    {
        // Prepend children to parent node in reverse order
        foreach (HtmlNode node in item.ChildNodes.Reverse())
        {
            item.ParentNode.PrependChild(node);
        }                        
    }
    else
    {
        // Insert children after previous sibling
        foreach (HtmlNode node in item.ChildNodes)
        {
            item.ParentNode.InsertAfter(node, item.PreviousSibling);
        }
    }

    // remove from tree
    item.Remove();
}

// return transformed doc
html = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo().Trim();
```

Here are the cases I used to test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripSingleTag()
{
    var input = "<p>tag</p>";
    var expected = "tag";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripNestedTag()
{
    var input = "<p>tag <p>inner</p></p>";
    var expected = "tag inner";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripTwoTopLevelTags()
{
    var input = "<p>tag</p> <div>block</div>";
    var expected = "tag block";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "div");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripMultipleNestedTags_2LevelsDeep()
{
    var input = "<p>tag <div>inner</div></p>";
    var expected = "tag inner";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "div");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripMultipleNestedTags_3LevelsDeep()
{
    var input = "<p>tag <div>inner <p>superinner</p></div></p>";
    var expected = "tag inner superinner";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "div");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripTwoTopLevelMultipleNestedTags_3LevelsDeep()
{
    var input = "<p>tag <div>inner <p>superinner</p></div></p> <div><p>inner</p> toplevel</div>";
    var expected = "tag inner superinner inner toplevel";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "div");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_IgnoresTagsThatArentSpecified()
{
    var input = "<p>tag <div>inner <a>superinner</a></div></p>";
    var expected = "tag inner <a>superinner</a>";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "div");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    input = "<wrapper><p>tag <div>inner</div></p></wrapper>";
    expected = "<wrapper>tag inner</wrapper>";
    actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "div");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void StripTags_CanStripSelfClosingAndUnclosedTagsLikeBr()
{
    var input = "<p>tag</p><br><br/>";
    var expected = "tag";
    var actual = HtmlUtilities.StripTags(input, "p", "br");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

It may not handle everything probably but it works for my needs.

Comment: it's working great, maybe people are lazy to read you answer , as it's the longest

Comment: Only right solution in this thread. Made similar things few years back and came here to refresh my memory :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way:

```
 element.InnerHtml = element.InnerHtml.Replace("<br>", "{1}"); 
 var innerTextWithBR = element.InnerText.Replace("{1}", "<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this might be what you're looking for?

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//removeme"))
{
    HtmlNodeCollection children = node.ChildNodes; //get <removeme>'s children
    HtmlNode parent = node.ParentNode; //get <removeme>'s parent
    node.Remove(); //remove <removeme>
    parent.AppendChildren(children); //append the children to the parent
}
```

*Edit: L.B's answer is much cleaner. Go with his!*

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var removedNodes = document.SelectNodes("//removeme");
if(removedNodes != null)
    foreach(var rn in removedNodes){
        HtmlTextNode innernodes =document.CreateTextNode(rn.InnerHtml);
        rn.ParnetNode.ReplaceChild(innernodes, rn);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally the correct expression would be `node.ParentNode.RemoveChildren(node, true)`.

Due to a ordering bug in `HtmlNode.RemoveChildren()` (http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions/79587), I have created a method that is similar.  Sorry it's in VB.  If anyone wants a translation I'll write one.

```
'The HTML Agility Pack (1.4.9) includes the HtmlNode.RemoveChild() method but it has an ordering bug with preserving child nodes.  
'The below implementation orders children correctly.
Private Shared Sub RemoveNode(node As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode, keepChildren As Boolean)
    Dim parent = node.ParentNode
    If keepChildren Then
        For i = node.ChildNodes.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            parent.InsertAfter(node.ChildNodes(i), node)
        Next
    End If
    node.Remove()
End Sub
```

I have tested this code with the following test markup:

```
<removeme>
    outertextbegin
    <p>innertext1</p>
    <p>innertext2</p>
    outertextend
</removeme>
```

The output is:

```
outertextbegin
<p>innertext1</p>
<p>innertext2</p>
outertextend
```

Answer (score 0):

This is version in C# - answer for post from  Dec 3 '14 at 17:57 - pseudocoder

The site did not allow me to comment and add to the original post. Maybe it will help someone.

```
private void removeNode(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node, bool keepChildren)
{
    var parent = node.ParentNode;
    if (keepChildren)
    {
        for ( int i = node.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            parent.InsertAfter(node.ChildNodes[i], node);
        }            
    }
    node.Remove(); 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

with regex you can do or you need to do with htmlagilitypack?

```
string html = "<ul><removeMe><li><a href="#">Keep me</a></li></removeMe></ul>";

html = Regex.Replace(html, "<removeMe.*?>", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
html = Regex.Replace(html, "</removeMe>", "", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```