# Duplicating HtmlNode in HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm using HTML Agility Pack to do two different things on the same page.
For the first one I need to remove element like script, style etc.
However for the second one, I must keep all of the elements.

Since I can't do the second part before the first one, I'm looking for a way to duplicate the object at first, so I can save all of the elements for the second part.
That is the code I tried, but for some reson I do not get the nodes inside it.

```
        HtmlDocument HTMLdoc = new HtmlDocument();
        HTMLdoc.LoadHtml(sFetch);

        //duplicate document node
        var webPage = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<html></html>");
        webPage.CopyFrom(HTMLdoc.DocumentNode,true);
```

Another way I've thought of is to invert the xpath that select all the elements I with to remove. so I'll be able to select just them without really removing elements from the object.
But I can't figure out how to use the XPath "not()" function to invert my query.
that's my XPath query:

```
"//script | //style | //iframe | //select | //textarea | //comment() | //a[@href]"
```

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: [Html Agility Pack - Remove element, but not innerHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092575/html-agility-pack-remove-element-but-not-innerhtml)

Comment: @L.B I can't understand how that's answering my question...
I don't want to keep the InnerHtml. I want to keep the whole node.

Comment: Can you post a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an *inverted* version of your XPath expression:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//node()[not(self::script or self::style or self::iframe or self::select or self::textarea or self::comment() or self::a[@href])]")
    .ToList();
```

This will select nodes except scripts, styles, etc.

Comment: It doesn't help me since I must keep the documentNode as is and not remove it's nodes.

Comment: @meirlo, updated my answer with *inverted* version of your xpath

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar. I had to get this info and then convert it to XML. Here is what you need:

```
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(sfetch);

        HtmlNodeCollection page = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");//whatever tags your are looking for in your doc

        foreach (HtmlNode value in page)
        {
            richTxtboxFilteredHTML.Text += value.InnerText;
        }
```

If you're going to process this further, you will need to keep referencing each HtmlNode.