# Removing Html tags while preserving inner text and <br> tags

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to remove span,font, b, s, strike (and other inner element) tags from HTML content while preserving text and `<br>` tags inside it. For this purpose I'm using HTML agility pack. I managed to preserve text but `<br>` tags are still a problem. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
 private void removeTagsButPreserveText2(HtmlNode nodeToRemove)
    {
        var parent = nodeToRemove.ParentNode;
        var prev = nodeToRemove.PreviousSibling;

        if (prev != null)
        {
            var child = nodeToRemove.SelectNodes("./br");

            if (child == null)
            {
                parent.InsertAfter(documentToSearch.CreateTextNode(nodeToRemove.InnerText + " "), prev);

                nodeToRemove.Remove();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in child)
                {
                    var parent2 = item.PreviousSibling;

                    if (parent2 != null)
                    {
                        if (parent2.InnerText.HasDate())
                        {
                            var newNode = parent.InsertAfter(documentToSearch.CreateTextNode(parent2.InnerText), prev);
                            parent.InsertAfter(documentToSearch.CreateElement("br"), newNode);
                            nodeToRemove.Remove();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For example, input will be:

```
<p><font face="Arial" size="2"><strike>
        <span style="font-weight: 400"><font color="#000000">Paper 
        Submission (Full 
        Paper) Before
        <span lang="en-us">September</span> 20, 201<span lang="en-us">2</span></font></span></strike><font color="#FF0000"><br>
        Notification of 
        Acceptance On <span lang="en-us">October 5</span>, 201<span lang="en-us">2</span><br>
        Authors' 
        Registration Before
        <span lang="en-us">October 20</span>, 201<span lang="en-us">2</span><br>
        ICNIT 2012 Conference 
        Dates November 
        17 - 18, 2012</font></font></p>
```

and the output should look like this:

```
<p>Paper Submission (Full Paper) Before September 20, 2012<br>
        Notification of Acceptance On October 5, 2012<br>
        Authors' Registration Before October 20, 2012<br>
        ICNIT 2012 Conference 
        Dates November 
        17 - 18, 2012</p>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the goal behind doing this?

Comment: can you replace you <br/> to \t (let jsut say) before 'cleaning-up', and then covert it back to <br/>?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I'm extracting some information from HTML pages. These inner elements making it really hard, so I want to remove them.

Comment: @RadeMilovic can you post a *simple* input and expected output.

Comment: OK `InnerText` doesn't give the exact output you expect but Why is it  not enough?

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this topic?
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154046/3424212](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154046/3424212)

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of HTML manipulation, there's a great library called the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Here's a similar question which will point to the right direction: [Html Agility Pack - Remove element, but not innerHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092575/html-agility-pack-remove-element-but-not-innerhtml)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use **regular expressions** for that? I mean, get everything into "`<xxxx asdasd>`" or something like that and replace per "" maintaining only `<BR>`?

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: I'm parsing a lot of HTML. Regex will slow it down even more.

Comment: Medeiros, Welcome to stackoverflow. See this classic reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags about parsing html with regex