# How do I remove all HTML tags from a string without knowing which tags are in it?

Tags: c#, html

Is there any easy way to remove all HTML tags or ANYTHING HTML related from a string?

For example:

```
string title = "<b> Hulk Hogan's Celebrity Championship Wrestling &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#228b22\">[Proj # 206010]</font></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Reality Series, &nbsp;)"
```

The above should really be:

"Hulk Hogan's Celebrity Championship Wrestling [Proj # 206010] (Reality Series)"

Comment: This question is closed due to duplication but suggested answer is given using Html Agility Pack. If you want to remove html tags with out using Html Agility pack you can refer my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/30026043/2318354 . Which may be helpful to some one

Comment: This is not a duplicate, as "HTML agility pack - removing unwanted tags without removing content?" wants to keep some tags (ie, give a list of valid tags, remove the rest). This question here is about removing ALL tags. And I can't use the other question's answers as I'm not going to pass in a list of all html tags in existence.

Comment: Take a look at [xidel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xidel/). It will take you 95% of the way there with `xidel -s input -e '/'`.

Answer (score 398, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

**Be aware that this solution has its own flaw.** See [Remove HTML tags in String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878452/remove-html-tags-in-string) for more information (especially the comments of 'Mark E. Haase'/@mehaase)

Another solution would be to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).
You can find an example using the library here: [HTML agility pack - removing unwanted tags without removing content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787449/html-agility-pack-removing-unwanted-tags-without-removing-content)

Comment: Doesn't work for input: '7 < 10 <b>but</b> 30 > 10' it gives: '7 but 30 > 10'

Comment: Yes, because it strips everything between < and >, so in your case, `< 10 <b>` and `</b>` are both stripped.

Comment: Shouldn't the method name be StripHtml() since method names should use Pascal case?

Comment: Using regular expressions for this is probably not a good idea if you are using it for security reasons.

Comment: Just change the regex to <[a-zA-Z/]*?>

Comment: @BrandonPrudent maybe better would be `<[a-zA-Z/].*?>` - it includes attributes

Comment: I think this Regex considers almost every case <[\/a-zA-Z0-9= \" \\" \' \\' #;:()$_-]*?>

Comment: C# code will  be: Regex.Replace(input, "<[\\/a-zA-Z0-9= \"\\\"'\'#;:()$_-]*?>", string.Empty);

Answer (score 86):

You can parse the string using [Html Agility pack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) and get the InnerText.

```
    HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(@"<b> Hulk Hogan's Celebrity Championship Wrestling &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#228b22\">[Proj # 206010]</font></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Reality Series, &nbsp;)");
    string result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

Comment: I like the `InnerText` solution as it removes all tags. But... it leaves behind `&nbsp;` and also comment tags such as `<!-- xxx --> ` like those surrounding `v:shapetype`, `v:shape` or `v:imagedata` with `[if gte vml 1]` or `[if !vml]`

Comment: I realize that `&nbsp;` is an html entity, not a tag, so a solution to remove that could be `result = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(result);` and to remove the comment nodes, using the Html Agility Pack: `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()")?.ForEach(c=> c.Remove());` just before doing `result = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerText;`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below code on your string and you will get the complete string without html part.

```
string title = "<b> Hulk Hogan's Celebrity Championship Wrestling &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color=\"#228b22\">[Proj # 206010]</font></b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Reality Series, &nbsp;)".Replace("&nbsp;",string.Empty);            
        string s = Regex.Replace(title, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

I built a small function to remove HTML tags.

```
public static string RemoveHtmlTags(string text)
        {
            List<int> openTagIndexes = Regex.Matches(text, "<").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index).ToList();
            List<int> closeTagIndexes = Regex.Matches(text, ">").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Index).ToList();
            if (closeTagIndexes.Count > 0)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                int previousIndex = 0;
                foreach (int closeTagIndex in closeTagIndexes)
                {
                    var openTagsSubset = openTagIndexes.Where(x => x >= previousIndex && x < closeTagIndex);
                    if (openTagsSubset.Count() > 0 && closeTagIndex - openTagsSubset.Max() > 1 )
                    {
                        sb.Append(text.Substring(previousIndex, openTagsSubset.Max() - previousIndex));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(text.Substring(previousIndex, closeTagIndex - previousIndex + 1));
                    }
                    previousIndex = closeTagIndex + 1;
                }
                if (closeTagIndexes.Max() < text.Length)
                {
                    sb.Append(text.Substring(closeTagIndexes.Max() + 1));
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                return text;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
    if (input==null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This solution is already provided

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string StripHtml(string input)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? input : System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static Regex htmlRegex = new Regex("<.*?>", RegexOptions.Compiled);
   
public static string RemoveHTMLTagsCompiled(string html)
{
 return htmlRegex.Replace(html, string.Empty);
}
```