# How to remove anchor tags alone but keep the text within a json data

Tags: c#

I have a json data which contains hundreds of data like the below format.

```
records: [
{
0: "<a name="3096" href="xxx">3096</a>",
1: "02/03/2016",
},
{
0: "<a name="3097" href="yyy">3097</a>",
1: "02/03/2016",
}]
```

Before deserializing it I need to remove the anchor tags from each record but keep the inner text alone. It should be like

```
records: [
{
0: "3096",
1: "02/03/2016",
},
{
0: "3097",
1: "02/03/2016",
}]
```

How to do this in C#. Can anyone help.

Comment: So the data is a string and you whish to remove the HTML-tags before deserializing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer provided by [Bidou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2390175/bidou) here [How do I remove all HTML tags from a string without knowing which tags are in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it)

You can do something like this:

```
public static string YourMethod()
{  
    var bar = "records: [{0: \"<a name=\"3096\" href=\"xxx\">3096</a>\",1: \"02/03/2016\",},{0: \"<a name=\"3097\" href=\"yyy\">3097</a>\",1: \"02/03/2016\",}]";
    var result = StripHTML(bar);
    return result;
}

public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

It will return:

```
records: [{0: "3096",1: "02/03/2016",},{0: "3097",1: "02/03/2016",}]
```

Another option is to serialize it to your class first, and then remove the anchor tags from the "1" property only. You may also check your json-model since 0 and 1 isn't valid property names in C#. Will it be serialized into a `Dictionary`? In that case you may reconsider storing them as such:

```
string json = @"{""key1"":""value1"",""key2"":""value2""}";

Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

As mentioned here: [How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,string> in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net)

Comment: Awesome.Thanks for the solution. It works perfectly.