# C# HTML string -> get length without html

Tags: c#, html, string, image

I have string with HTML images, for example:

```
string str = "There is some nice <img alt='img1' src='img/img1.png' /> images in this <img alt='img2' src='img/img2.png' /> string. I would like to ask you <img alt='img3' src='img/img3.png' /> how Can I can I get the Lenght of the string?";
```

I would like to get the lenght of the string without the images and the count of images. So, the result should be:

```
int strLenght = 111;
int imagesCount= 3;
```

Can you show me the most effective way, please?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this with the help of RegularExpression.
Please let me know if you need solution based on it

Comment: Take a look to this answer to remove HTML tags: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18154046/5119765 Then you'll be able to get the string length.

Comment: Your best option would be to use a html parser like [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) so you can properly count the character length of the content and the number of image tags.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest to use a real HTML parser, for example [`HtmlAgilityPack`](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). Then it's simple:

```
string html = "There is some nice <img alt='img1' src='img/img1.png' /> images in this <img alt='img2' src='img/img2.png' /> string. I would like to ask you <img alt='img3' src='img/img3.png' /> how Can I can I get the Lenght of the string?";

var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
int length = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText.Length;               // 114
int imageCount = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img").Count(); // 3
```

This is what `DocumentNode.InnerText` returns in your sample, you've skipped some spaces:

```
There is some nice  images in this  string. I would like to ask you  how Can I can I get the Lenght of the string?
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and I've created this method.
You can use it to strip HTML tags and count your string

```
public static string StripHtmlTags(string source)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
  {
    return string.Empty;
  }

  var array = new char[source.Length];
  int arrayIndex = 0;
  bool inside = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
  {
    char let = source[i];
    if (let == '<')
    {
      inside = true;
      continue;
    }

    if (let == '>')
    {
      inside = false;
      continue;
    }

    if (!inside)
    {
      array[arrayIndex] = let;
      arrayIndex++;
    }
  }

  return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
}
```

your counting would be like:

```
int strLength = StripHtmlTags(str).Count;
```

Comment: You know you could just do `foreach(char let in source)` instead since `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 2):

Add a (COM) reference to MSHTML (Microsoft HTML object lib) and you can:

```
var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)new HTMLDocument();
doc.write(str);

Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", doc.body.innerText.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Images: {0}", doc.images.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to do it with the help of RegularExpression as i mentioned in my comment above. Please use following code

```
var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("<img[^>]*/>");
var plainString = regex.Replace(str, ""); 

// plainString.length will be string length without images
    var cnt = regex.Matches(str).Count; // cnt will be number of images
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked John Smith solution, however I had to add `Trim()` at the end to match the MS Word result.

Use this:

```
return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex).Trim();
```