# get string value between Special character and replace string in c#

Tags: c#

I want to get and replace the string between special character.
e.g. myString = "hello my first string is {String Name} and my Second string is {String Name}"

I want to replace the string between "{" "}".

Comment: Possible solution is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-text-that-lies-between-parentheses-round-brackets

Comment: could you describe a little more in detail, can the string vary between the {} and what do you want as the replacement? do you want to replace all values with one ? or each has to be individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a Regex like this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "{.*?}", replaceString);
```

For example:

```
 string input = "This is the {text}";
 string replace = "content";

 string result = Regex.Replace(input, "{.*?}", replace);
```

See also [How do I remove all HTML tags from a string without knowing which tags are in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it/18154046#18154046)

Answer (score 0):

```
string content = "{dsdhs},{sdsds}";
List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
Regex topicRegex = new Regex(@"\{(.*?)\}", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match item in topicRegex.Matches(content))
                    tempList.Add(item.Value);
```

Comment: You should add description/comments, Please refer: [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This may helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex`

```
var input = "User Name {stringToReplace}";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @" ?\{.*?\}", "NewString");

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

[.netFiddleLink](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sgL0z2)

Answer (score 0):

People are giving regex answers but it sounds more like you're describing string interpolation.

```
var string1 = "string 1";
var string2 = "string 2";
var myString = $"hello my first string is {string1} and my Second string is {string2}";
```

For a more detailed explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: In the title he wrote "between Special character", which means it could be something else....

Comment: It really depends on what he is trying to do.