# How to remove these kinds of "tags" from html strings?

Tags: c#, html

I'm not even sure if tags is the right word.

But I am talking about these elements: `</ul> <ul> <li>`

For example, what would I use to get rid of those types of characters from this string: `<i>A lethal crawfish with extremely dangerous claws.</i>`?

EDIT: I am not webscraping but accessing a sqlite database that still contain these elements and I would like to remove them before outputting them.

Comment: Use HTMLAgilityPack. It helps you to modify html with XPath.

Comment: You can get it from Nuget.

Comment: I am not webscraping however, merely just taking strings out of a sqlite database that still contain these elements.

Comment: Of course, you can use any strings with "tags". you just pick the node, and do someNode.innerText.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an html sanitizer. I'm guessing you are trying to clean HTML inputted by a user... they could input things far nastier than `<ul>`. a sanitizer will help you mitigate this possibility.

you can Google for them or take a look through nuget, just found this one via Google: https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer

Comment: Ah, no. I'm using someone's scraper and it saved into a sqlite database. However, some of the strings still contain those elements.

Answer (score 0):

```css
Original String: <h4>Hello   World</h4>
Replacement String: Hello   World
```

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
         string input = "<h4>Hello   World</h4>";
         string pattern = "<[^>]*>";
         string replacement = "";
         Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
         string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

         Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
         Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);    
         Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use  Can Follow [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it)