# Retrieving an element from JSON response

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I am trying to get a field from the response from the rest services in the Web API we are building. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
"d": {
    "results": [{
        "__metadata": {
            "id": "Web/Lists(guid'4ddc-41e2-bb44-0f92ad2c0b07')/Items(164)",
            "uri": "https://teams.ax.org/sites/js/project/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4ddc-41e2-bb44-0f92ad2c0b07')/Items(164)",
            "etag": "\"6\"",
            "type": "SP.Data.St_x0020_CdsListItem"
        },
        "Folder": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://teams.ax.org/sites/js/project/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4ddc-41e2-bb44-0f92ad2c0b07')/Items(164)/Folder"
            }
        },
        "ParentList": {
            "__deferred": {
                "uri": "https://teams.ax.org/sites/js/project/_api/Web/Lists(guid'4ddc-41e2-bb44-0f92ad2c0b07')/Items(164)/ParentList"
            }
        },
        "PM_x0020_NameId": 220,
        "St_x0020_Name": "<div class=\"ExternalClassA14DB0FF86994403B827D91158CF34B0\">KO</div>",
    }]
}}
```

I created these model classes:

```
 public class SharepointDTO
 {
    public class Metadata
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("uri")]
        public string uri { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("etag")]
        public string etag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Deferred
    {
        [JsonProperty("uri")]
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    public class Folder
    {
        [JsonProperty("__deferred")]
        public Deferred __deferred { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentList
    {
        [JsonProperty("__deferred")]
        public Deferred __deferred { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("__metadata")]
        public Metadata __metadata { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Folder")]
        public Folder Folder { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ParentList")]
        public ParentList ParentList { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("PM_x0020_NameId")]
        public int PM_x0020_NameId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("St_x0020_Name")]
        public string St_x0020_Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class D
    {
        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public IList<Result> results { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("d")]
        public D d { get; set; }
    }
}
```

No trying to call the rest service from the Web API and need to get the St_x0020_Name from response and store in a string.

```
  SharepointDTO.RootObject retSharepointobj = await GetfromSharepoint(StNumber);
  string StName = retSharepointobj.d.results.St_x0020_Name.ToString();
```

[image]

I am deserializing the JSON in the `GetfromSharepoint` method like

```
using (var client_sharePoint = new HttpClient(handler))
{
    var response = client_sharePoint.GetAsync(SP_URL).Result;

    var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SharepointDTO.RootObject>(responsedata);

    return returnObj;
}
```

But it throws an error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' does not contain a definition for 'St_x0020_Name' and no extension method 'St_x0020_Name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array, so you have either loop thru like

```
foreach(var item in retSharepointobj.d.results){
   string StName = item.St_x0020_Name.ToString();
}
```

or get a specific element, for example a first element like:

```
SharepointDTO.RootObject retSharepointobj = await GetfromSharepoint(StNumber);
string StName = retSharepointobj.d.results[0].St_x0020_Name.ToString();
```

or you can add an extra check like that

```
SharepointDTO.RootObject retSharepointobj = await GetfromSharepoint(StNumber);
if(retSharepointobj.d.results.length > 0){
    string StName = retSharepointobj.d.results[0].St_x0020_Name.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But I am getting the entire `<div class=\"ExternalClassA14DB0FF86994403B827D91158CF34B0\">KO</div>` in to the string how can I get only the `KO` which is in between the div tags.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this line:

```
string StName = retSharepointobj.d.results.St_x0020_Name.ToString();
```

Be like this?

```
string StName = retSharepointobj.d.results.First().St_x0020_Name.ToString();
```

Comment: But I am getting the entire <div class=\"ExternalClassA14DB0FF86994403B827D91158CF34B0\">KO</‌​div> in to the string how can I get only the KO which is in between the div tags.

Comment: That is a different problem now. You may want to look at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it