# Remove html mark ups from the string c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string that has HTML mark ups like below

```
results[1] = &lt;div class="ExternalClassAE850B41EF"&gt;&lt;p&gt;​&lt;span&gt;G_Pck&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
```

I want to extract the mark ups and just store G_Pc. I did use the Regex Function like below

```
string StTag = results[i].ToString();
var b = Regex.Match(StTag, "(?<=>)(.*)(?=<)");
```

But still I see the the span and p tags in the `b`. How can I escape those tags too

Comment: Use             System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and             System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: Why don't you replace all <[^>]*> with an empty string?

Comment: [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) should probably help.

Comment: If you can guarantee that string conforms to a well-defined Xml Fragment you could XDocument.Parse it and then use `Descendants("span").First().Value` to get that value you're after. Otherwise use an html parser. Better not [regex too much...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @jdweng tried to use the `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode` like string `StTag = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(results[i].ToString());` still seeing the same issue

Comment: @Sach I installed HTMLAgility but when I use `HtmlDocument` itsays missing assembly reference

Comment: Which assembly reference? You can use NuGet to install it without missing anything.

Comment: You have double quotes in the string so make sure you put a backslash before the two double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
public static string StripHTML(string input)
{
  return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
}
```

**Be aware** that this solution has its own flaw. See [Answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it)