# How to debug a Bot Framework BOT running on Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding, microsoft-teams

I uploaded a BOT in Microsoft Teams, but for some reason, it behaves different than other channels. The bot wont understand my input, and LUIS would return none intent.

In other channels it works well, as well in the BOT Emulator.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/general/debug) appear to be MS documentation about it, but it doesn't really explain what I need.

There's a way for me to debug the BOT running on Microsoft Teams??

Please! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

[Ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/) is a good tool for setting up your bot on azure and debugging locally. This will help to find issues as you can walk through your code as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to see where specifically your code is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with LUIS using Microsoft Teams was that the activity receive the message in HTML. I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it) that helped me eliminate the HTML tags. On the other hand, Ngrok is the tool needed to accomplish remote debugging, and [this blog](https://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2018/04/run-your-app-in-teams-but-debug-locally-using-ngrok-heres-how/) describe the steps very well.

Answer (score 0):

Please also look at Jmeter with

> [BotServiceStressToolkit](https://github.com/damadei/BotServiceStressToolkit)

Which allows you to do some testing without Ngrok directly to your IIS Express instance while debugging.