# Would like to count the characters in a string excluding rich text formatting? (C#)

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, character, richtext

**Platform**: Unity 2018.2.20f1
**Language**: C# .Net 4.x

### Scenario

I have a string which I would apply to a textmesh rendered​ in Unity. This rendering pipeline supports Rich text editing. 
http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/

### Request

Hence when I supply in a string, I would like to know character count which would exclude the characters used for Rich Text formatting.

### Example

```
string _value = "We are <b><i>definitely not</i></b> amused";
// Character count should be 29 instead of 43
```

So what is the best way to implement it? Is there a module/resources online that would assist me in extracting the count?

Thank you, 
Karsnen

Comment: Stripping the tags with regex comes to mind, perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18154046/7703386) answer might be helpful?

Comment: Thank you @Wubbler. I was also thinking about regex as the possible way. Will try to implement it.

Comment: Have you looked at their scripting API? Is there not a method to get raw text from the object?

How are you populating the object?

Comment: Austin, yes and thank you for chiming in. I have mentioned that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

**For non-unity developers**

From my understanding, you will have to use the Regex expressions to solve it. Something like @Wubber && @Yakov have suggested. 
[Another answer with suggested by Wubber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it/18154046#18154046)

**For Unity Devs using TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI**

```
TMPro.TMP_InputField myInputField;
TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI InputTextBoxField;

private void onValueChangedInMyInputField(string _value)
{
  int _charCount = InputTextBoxField.GetParsedText().Length;
  int _inputFieldCount = myInputField.text.Length;
  // _charCount is the number excluding the rich text content 
  // _inputFieldCount is the number inclusive of the rich text content
}
```

Thank you for your time, everyone. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can set how it replaces the formatting block.

```
string CountNumber = Regex.Replace(richtextbox, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
MessageBox.Show(CountNumber.Length);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As much that would be the right way to implement it, I guess the regex pattern has to be expanded to be inclusive of all expectations. besides that, it will work.