# How can I get text value of TMPro Text without markup tags in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am trying to get text value in TMPro Text component without markup tags but haven't found any solutions.

Say, `<b><color=red>Hello </color><b> world` is the value in TMPro Text, and I just want `Hello world` in c# script.

Bear in mind that tag `<b>` and color will change, so I would love to remove tags dynamically, meaning I would like not to replacing each tag by `text.replace("<b>", "")` kind of things.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153998/how-do-i-remove-all-html-tags-from-a-string-without-knowing-which-tags-are-in-it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TMP_Text.GetParsedText ()` to get the text after it has been parsed and rich text tags removed.

Alternatively you can also use **regular expressions** to search a string for rich text tags, and remove them while preserving the rest of the string.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
public static string GetString (string str)
{
    Regex rich = new Regex (@"<[^>]*>");

    if (rich.IsMatch (str))
    {
        str = rich.Replace (str, string.Empty);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the option of using HTML on tmp but you can attach the text to your script by create a new variable like that:

```
[SerializeField] TMP_Text textVar;
```

then you can drag you tmp game object to the component that include this script

and the you can change the text like that:

```
textVar.text = "what ever";
```

or get text like that:

```
string textString = textVar.text;
```

for the color you can use

```
Color color = textVar.color;
```