# HtmlAgilityPack - Remove child nodes but retain inner text for the main node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the inner text from a node but it has child nodes and its text is in the middle of its child entries i.e:

```
<script1>
 <p1>lalala</p1>
 "script text"
</script1>
```

The code I need is inside script1, but if I try and get innertext I get all of the inside of p1 too..

Cannot figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092575/html-agility-pack-remove-element-but-not-innerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(MyTextHtml);

    HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p1/following-sibling::text()");
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText.Trim());
```

will output this:

```
"script text"
```

Here is link on [XPATH axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) that should get you started.